# Medical insurance for students in Italy

Tags: visa, resident-permit, student-visa, italy

I am Moroccan. I recently received Italy student visa. I was required to present medical insurance in the application. When I go to Italy, I need to apply for residence permit. To apply, you need to present medical insurance, It s originally in French. When I go, should it be translated to Italian or they will accept such medical insurance in French as well?

Comment: Medical insurance doesn't have a language *per se*. I am guessing you're referring to a specific document in your possession but it's important to be precise. It's perfectly possible to have an insurance contract drafted in one language but to have your insurer provide a statement of your coverage in another language (e.g. English).

Comment: In your case, I don't know if a document in French would be acceptable but more importantly I assume that you require insurance that would cover you in Italy as a resident. Does your current insurance cover that? Does the document you have spell that out in sufficient details (level of coverage, etc.)?

Comment: @Relaxed Yes. It is valid in Italy. It covers me in Italy. It indicates every detail. But, it is in French.

Comment: It covers you *as a resident* in Italy? It seems unusual to me (but I upvoted the question anyway). I would still recommend explaining what is in French (i.e. what document you are referring to) and asking your insurer if they can provide something else (if they specifically offer international insurance, they might).

Comment: @Relaxed Ok. the insurance is valid in Europe. It is an international insurance. I am 100% sure. Now, the question is, if the insurance is in French, would it be accepted in Italy, only as it is in French, not whether it can be accepted in Italy or not as an insurance. The insurance has a bar code for verification.

Comment: Whether it was “valid in Europe” is not what I asked though. Insurance always comes with more specific conditions. I asked whether it covers you as a resident in Europe and for how long. That and the level of coverage is what decides whether this insurance contract meets the requirement.

Comment: Strictly speaking, “insurance is in French” doesn't even make sense. Insurance is a service, it's not in a language. So if you do have a contract that covers healthcare after residing for more than a short time in a foreign country, I wonder whether the insurer can provide a document stating that in another language. Expat insurance does exist but it's a very specific service and as many European countries have mandatory insurance requirements, I would expect companies providing this to be able to issue a document in a major European language.

Comment: @Relaxed The document is issued in French language. It covers me as a student. So the insurance provider does issue it in French, English, and Spanish. But, not in Italian, so, my question is: Will Italian authorities require me to translate it Italian, or they will recognize as a service, regardless of whether it is in any language as long as it is valid. Consider you are American, you went to an American insurance issuer that is valid in Europe, thus, in Italy, but it issued it in English. Would you translate it in Italian?

Comment: Thanks, that's clear, I guess what I am trying to tell you is that you could edit the question to explain that a little more carefully. That's all.

Comment: @Relaxed Ok, but you haven't answered my question yet. Would you translate it?

Comment: If I knew the answer, I would post an answer! Comments are just that and are there to help refine the question.